# How to pull a different value from google sheets each time it runs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

So I am trying to pull the value that is in the latest line of `google sheets`. Here is the part of the script that I am having trouble with. This script is being written within google scripts.

When this script runs the confirmation email it sends has the value of var cell as `undefined`. 0

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {
  var userEmail = e.values[3];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Set the status of the new ticket to 'New'.
  // Column F is the Status column
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");
  var supportEmail;

  // Calculate how many other 'New' tickets are ahead of this one
  var numNew = 0;
  for (var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i, getColIndexByName("Status")).getValue() == "New") {
      numNew++;
    }
  }

  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B100");

  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
  Logger.log(values[0][0]);
  for(n=0;n<values[0].length;++n){
    var cell = values[n][1]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(n=0;n<values[0].length;++n){
    var cell = values[n][1]
  }
```

*values[0].length* is the number of columns while *values[n][1]* goes through rows.

if you need a loop to go over the rows use this:

```
for(n=0;n<values.length;++n){
        var cell = values[n][1]
      }
```

Otherwise if you have 10 columns and 50 rows, your loop will only go up to ten as *values[0].length* is 10 and you will pull data from:

1. A1
2. A2
3. A3
4. A4

and etc until

10. A10

and then loop will stop.

Comment: Please check it as answered. Thanks